# Delegation of simple type methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, delegation

I'm currently digging deeper in the really nice prototypical delegation of Objects in JavaScript. As far as I understood the simple types (Numbers, strings and booleans) as well as functions and arrays get their base methods delegated from the `Object.prototype`. A good example is the `toString`methods. Because of JavaScripts mutability of Objects it is possible to change these methods. Also because of it's dynamical nature, these changes will be immediately available to all prototypes that are linked to the `Object.prototype`.

Here is a basic example of how dynamical prototype linkage should work:

```
var myFirstObject = {
  myMethod: function () {
    console.log('this is the method from myFirstObject');
  }
},

mySecondObject = Object.create(myFirstObject);
mySecondObject.myMethod(); // "this is the method from myFirstObject"

myFirstObject.myMethod = function () {
  console.log('this is a dynamic change of myMethod from myFirstObject');
};

mySecondObject.myMethod(); // "this is a dynamic change of myMethod from myFirstObject"

mySecondObject.myMethod = function () {
  console.log('this is the method from mySecondObject')
};

mySecondObject.myMethod(); // "this is the method from mySecondObject"

delete mySecondObject.myMethod;

mySecondObject.myMethod(); // "this is a dynamic change of myMethod from myFirstObject"
```

However this doesn't seems to work as expected for the default methods like `toString`:

```
var myFunction = function () {};

Object.prototype.myCustomMethod = function () {
  console.log('This is a custom function on the Object prototype');
};

myFunction.myCustomMethod(); // "This is a custom function on the Object prototype"

Object.prototype.toString = function () {
  console.log('Don\'t mess around with the Object prototype default methods');
}

myFunction.toString(); // "function () {}" <-- ???

Function.prototype.toString = function () {
  console.log('Don\'t mess around with the Function prototype default methods');
};

myFunction.toString(); // "Don't mess around with the Function prototype default methods"

delete Function.prototype.toString;

myFunction.toString(); // "Don't mess around with the Object prototype default methods" <-- ???
```

So my question is: What kind of magic is happening for default methods like `toString` is there a real delegation between the `Object.prototype` and the `Function.prototype` or just a simple copy?

Comment: `Function` inherits from `Object` and overrides `toString`.

Comment: Also works for ``Number``, ``String`` and so on. You indicate that every type has it's own implementation of the default methods?

Comment: Yeah, that about sums it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called the "Prototype chain" and starts at the bottom and moves up eventually to `Object` which is the base for all objects types.

`Function` inherits the Object prototype and has its own prototype. So when the JavaScript interpreter sees `Function.toString` it will first look for `toString` in the `Function.prototype`. only if it can not be found will it move up to the next prototype, which in this case is the `Object.prototype` This is why you Object.toString is not called in the example you have given.

This is done for all object properties. It is important to note that each step up the prototype chain you go the longer it will take to access that property as the interpreter will always start at the bottom and work up. Each prototype search takes CPU cycles so it is best to have the method or property on the object you are accessing rather than have one common method further up the prototype chain, such as `Object`.

/* *Sorry I do not remember if it "down" or "up" the chain, will correct when I find the common vernacular for which direction Object is.* */

I now have the correct direction.

Comment: I had a look in Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and he states that it is up the chain. The main insight for me is that every type has it's own implementation of ``toString``. Until now I kind of thought that there is a general implementation of those methods but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: This "important to note" part of this answer is at best unsupported and at worst just wrong. Searching down (or up) the prototype chain is blindingly fast and hyper-optimized. There is no reason to worry how far up or down the method you are looking for is on the prototype chain.

Comment: It is true that most modern browser JS implementations are well optimized and the performance implications of a long prototype chain probably don't matter much. BUT, it is something to keep in mind if your code will be running in other environments. For instance I'm not sure all mobile browsers are as well optimized as the desktop browsers, or if the code is running via Rhino on some other kind of device, etc. @torazaburo

Comment: Blindingly fast and hyper-optimized do not mean instantly. For simple applications that use small amounts of data it is off course irrelevant, but if you are processing large amounts of data 100's of millions of words the position in the prototype chain of a function or property can have a significant impact on the performance of the code.

Comment: @Blindman67 I'd love to see some concrete proof or example of that. Actually, in many (one is tempted to say the majority of) cases the impact is zero. That is because the JIT interpreter quickly detects the structure of the prototypes and is able to make a single reference. The lesson here, then, is not to spend too much effort making shorter prototype chains (how long are they usually, anyway?), and to spend more effort writing code which does not make dynamic changes to prototypes, which forces the JIT to throw away its optimizations.

Comment: @UselessCode Confused by that comment. iOS devices run Safari, for example. In any case, slower mobile performance is going to affect the entire app, not just prototype chain searching time. If your app is too slow, there are probably about one hundred things you want to worry about before trying to make your prototype chains shorter.

Comment: @Torazaburo Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Performance 
I believe that best practice is always to ensure optimal performance. It may seem trivial to argue over a few hundred CPU cycles per operation but when you consider the aggregate the savings are substantial in terms of user experience and power consumption. If we could rely on a single interpreter to run our code then we could code with that in mind, but that is not the case so we must code to the common conventions. Avoid deeply nested prototype chains if you can.

Comment: @Blindman67 That assertion needs to backed up with real data. A simple analysis shows that accessing a property on a prototype is about 20% slower than accessing a property on the object itself. Accessing additional levels of prototypes has virtually no effect on access time. The reason is how the interpreters optimize prototype access. They detect in advance, or as they go along, that a particular property is on a second-level prototype and can jump directly to it.

Comment: @torazaburo I have given a reference MDN link above in my last comment and I have run a benchmark targeting length of time to make the same call from different levels of the prototype chain. It shows that there is a 5 to 10% decrease in performance (Chrome Version 45.0.2454.46 beta-m) for each step down the prototype chain. It is the time to call the function that increases not the run time of the function. Anyway I think the MDN reference validates my assertion and I will leave it to the readers to judge its reliability.

Comment: @Blindman67 Sure, let them judge. I would note that MDN is written by guys like you and me, and good as it is, I have found blatant errors and out-of-date information in it. In any case, these discussions about performance are lots of fun, but I have yet to see a case where it actually makes a difference in the real world. Merely asserting that there in theory could be cases where it does, does not really accomplish anything. If I had the choice between a clean design that involved an extra link in the prototype chain, and a bit of performance, the choice would be obvious.